# Grafica de Highcharts no respeta colores definidos por array

Tags: javascript, highcharts

Tengo el caso de una gráfica, la cual se le definen los colores que puede utilizar en un array.

```
colors: ['#01579B', '#0288D1', '#03A9F4', '#4FC3F7', '#81D4FA', '#DCE775', '#FFB74D', '#FFEE58', '#0277BD', '#4DB6AC', '#00E5FF']
```

El problema es que en algunos casos respeta el orden, y en otros no. Ya que empieza no con el primer color definido. Este problema solamente lo tengo con la gráfica de columnas combinadas.

El caso que si respeta los colores es:

http://jsfiddle.net/jf7kj6g1/15/

y el que no respeta los colores:

https://jsfiddle.net/npwetntb/3/

Si alguien pudiera indicarme cual es mi error para que así todos los gráficos puedan utilizar el mismo orden de colores, muy agradecido.

Snippet donde la gráfica si respeta los colores:

```js
 var contador = 0;
   var porcentajes = [
     85.3,
     85.3,
     85.3,
     85.3,
     85.3,
     85.3,
     85.3,
   ];
   Highcharts.chart('grafico0', {
     colors: ['#01579B', '#0288D1', '#03A9F4', '#4FC3F7', '#81D4FA', '#DCE775', '#FFB74D', '#FFEE58', '#0277BD', '#4DB6AC', '#00E5FF'],
     chart: {
       type: 'column'
     },
     title: {
       text: 'Eficiencia de Equipos de Aspersión, 01-Zona 1, Semana :15-12/02/2018 al 18/02/2018'
     },
     xAxis: {
       title: {
         enabled: true,
         text: ''
       },
       categories: ['05/02/2018 </br> 29064  ', '06/02/2018 </br> 29064  ', '07/02/2018 </br> 29064  ', '08/02/2018 </br> 29064  ', '09/02/2018 </br> 29064  ', '10/02/2018 </br> 29064  ', '11/02/2018 </br> 29064  ', ]
     },
     yAxis: [{
       tickInterval: 1,
       labels: {
         formatter: function() {
           var porcentaje = this.value * 100 / 24;
           return Highcharts.numberFormat(porcentaje, 2, '.', ',');
         }
       },
       min: 0,
       max: 24,
       title: {
         text: 'Porcentajes'
       },
       stackLabels: {
         enabled: true,
         style: {
           fontWeight: 'bold',
           color: 'gray'
         }
       }
     }, {
       min: 0,
       max: 10,
       title: {
         text: 'Porcentajes'
       },
       stackLabels: {
         enabled: true,
         style: {
           fontWeight: 'bold',
           color: 'gray'
         }
       },
       opposite: true
     }],
     tooltip: {
       headerFormat: '<b>{point.x}</b><br/>',
       pointFormat: '{series.name}: {point.y}<br/>Total: {point.stackTotal}'
     },
     plotOptions: {
       spline: {
         dataLabels: {
           enabled: true,
           formatter: function() {
             var porcentajeLabel = porcentajes[contador];
             contador += 1;
             return '<span style="color: #D500F9;">' + porcentajeLabel + '%</span>';
           },
         }
       },
       column: {
         stacking: 'normal',
         dataLabels: {
           enabled: true,
           color: 'black'
         }
       }
     },
     series: [{
         name: '62-Operando Sin Horometro                                                ',
         data: [
           13.50,
           0,
           0,
           0,
           0,
           0,
           0,
         ],
         index: 1,
         legendIndex: 13
       },
       {
         name: '57-Traslado Equipo De Riego Con Tractor                                  ',
         data: [
           6.00,
           0,
           0,
           0,
           3.00,
           0,
           0,
         ],
         index: 1,
         legendIndex: 12
       },
       {
         name: '43-Cambios De Posicion                                                   ',
         data: [
           3.00,
           2.00,
           2.00,
           2.00,
           6.00,
           0,
           0,
         ],
         index: 1,
         legendIndex: 11
       },
       {
         name: '42-Instalación De Equipo                                                 ',
         data: [
           0,
           0,
           1.00,
           2.00,
           0,
           0,
           2.00,
         ],
         index: 1,
         legendIndex: 10
       },
       {
         name: '41-Problemas Con Accesorios                                              ',
         data: [
           0,
           0,
           2.70,
           0,
           0,
           0,
           0,
         ],
         index: 1,
         legendIndex: 9
       },
       {
         name: '18-Instalacion de equipos de riego                                       ',
         data: [
           0,
           0,
           1.00,
           0,
           6.00,
           0,
           0,
         ],
         index: 1,
         legendIndex: 8
       },
       {
         name: '17-Falta de Agua                                                         ',
         data: [
           0,
           0,
           0,
           2.80,
           0,
           0,
           0,
         ],
         index: 1,
         legendIndex: 7
       },
       {
         name: '06-Falta de Combustible                                                  ',
         data: [
           0,
           16.00,
           0,
           0,
           0,
           24.00,
           16.00,
         ],
         index: 1,
         legendIndex: 6
       },
       {
         name: '01-Operación                                                             ',
         data: [
           1.50,
           6.00,
           17.30,
           17.20,
           9.00,
           0,
           6.00,
         ],
         index: 1,
         legendIndex: 5
       },
       {
         name: 'Meta',
         type: 'spline',
         data: [20.47,
           20.47,
           20.47,
           20.47,
           20.47,
           20.47,
           20.47,
         ],
         color: '#D500F9'
       }
     ]
   });
```

```html
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>
<div id="grafico0" style="min-width: 310px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
```

Snippet donde la gráfica no respeta los colores:

```js
var contador = 0;
var porcentajes = [
  85.3,
  85.3,
  85.3,
  85.3,
  85.3,
  85.3,
  85.3,
];
Highcharts.chart('grafico0', {
  colors: ['#01579B', '#0288D1', '#03A9F4', '#4FC3F7', '#81D4FA', '#DCE775', '#FFB74D', '#FFEE58', '#0277BD', '#4DB6AC', '#00E5FF'],
  chart: {
    type: 'column'
  },
  title: {
    text: 'Eficiencia de Equipos de Aspersión, 01-Zona 1, Semana :14-05/02/2018 al 11/02/2018'
  },
  xAxis: {
    title: {
      enabled: true,
      text: ''
    },
    categories: ['29/01/2018 </br> 29064  ', '30/01/2018 </br> 29064  ', '31/01/2018 </br> 29064  ', '01/02/2018 </br> 29064  ', '02/02/2018 </br> 29064  ', '03/02/2018 </br> 29064  ', '04/02/2018 </br> 29064  ', ]
  },
  yAxis: [{
    tickInterval: 1,
    labels: {
      formatter: function() {
        var porcentaje = this.value * 100 / 24;
        return Highcharts.numberFormat(porcentaje, 2, '.', ',');
      }
    },
    min: 0,
    max: 24,
    title: {
      text: 'Porcentajes'
    },
    stackLabels: {
      enabled: true,
      style: {
        fontWeight: 'bold',
        color: 'gray'
      }
    }
  }, {
    min: 0,
    max: 10,
    title: {
      text: 'Porcentajes'
    },
    stackLabels: {
      enabled: true,
      style: {
        fontWeight: 'bold',
        color: 'gray'
      }
    },
    opposite: true
  }],
  tooltip: {
    headerFormat: '<b>{point.x}</b><br/>',
    pointFormat: '{series.name}: {point.y}<br/>Total: {point.stackTotal}'
  },
  plotOptions: {
    spline: {
      dataLabels: {
        enabled: true,
        formatter: function() {
          var porcentajeLabel = porcentajes[contador];
          contador += 1;
          return '<span style="color: #D500F9;">' + porcentajeLabel + '%</span>';
        },
      }
    },
    column: {
      stacking: 'normal',
      dataLabels: {
        enabled: true,
        color: 'black'
      }
    }
  },
  series: [{
      name: '57-Traslado Equipo De Riego Con Tractor                                  ',
      data: [
        0,
        6.00,
        0,
        0,
        0,
        0,
        0,
      ],
      index: 1,
      legendIndex: 12
    },
    {
      name: '43-Cambios De Posicion                                                   ',
      data: [
        3.00,
        2.00,
        2.00,
        2.00,
        4.00,
        2.00,
        0,
      ],
      index: 1,
      legendIndex: 11
    },
    {
      name: '42-Instalación De Equipo                                                 ',
      data: [
        0,
        0,
        0,
        0,
        0,
        0,
        2.00,
      ],
      index: 1,
      legendIndex: 10
    },
    {
      name: '41-Problemas Con Accesorios                                              ',
      data: [
        3.00,
        0,
        2.00,
        3.00,
        2.00,
        2.00,
        2.00,
      ],
      index: 1,
      legendIndex: 9
    },
    {
      name: '18-Instalacion de equipos de riego                                       ',
      data: [
        0,
        6.00,
        0,
        0,
        0,
        0,
        0,
      ],
      index: 1,
      legendIndex: 8
    },
    {
      name: '17-Falta de Agua                                                         ',
      data: [
        0,
        4.00,
        2.00,
        0,
        0,
        2.00,
        2.00,
      ],
      index: 1,
      legendIndex: 7
    },
    {
      name: '08-Mantenimiento/servicio                                                ',
      data: [
        0,
        0,
        0,
        1.00,
        0,
        0,
        0,
      ],
      index: 1,
      legendIndex: 6
    },
    {
      name: '01-Operación                                                             ',
      data: [
        18.00,
        6.00,
        18.00,
        18.00,
        18.00,
        18.00,
        18.00,
      ],
      index: 1,
      legendIndex: 5
    },
    {
      name: 'Meta',
      type: 'spline',
      data: [20.47,
        20.47,
        20.47,
        20.47,
        20.47,
        20.47,
        20.47,
      ],
      color: '#D500F9'
    }
  ]
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>

<div id="grafico0" style="min-width: 310px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
```

Comment: te puedo dar una alternativa de solucion? es colocar en la serie la etiqueta `color : value` y te solucionara todo eso

Comment: Muchas gracias @JackNavaRow con tu alternativa logré solucionar el inconveniente, saludos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Una opcion facil es agregarle el color directo a la serie en formato hexadecimal como lo dice la [documentacion](https://www.highcharts.com/docs/chart-concepts/series)

```
 series: [{
     name: 'serie1 ',
     data: [13.50,0,0],
     color: '#FFFFFF'
   },{
     name: 'serie2 ',
     data: [20,3,4],
     color: '#000000'
   }]
```